# Why isn't my SVG being used as a repeating background image?

Tags: html, css, svg

So, this feels like a simple question, but I just can't figure out what's wrong. I want to have a div element with a background that's a striped color. To do this, I decided to try my hand at writing SVG just to keep as close to W3C code as possible. However, when I try to apply it, it just doesn't seem to work. **The SVG image does appear properly** when its raw code is embedded into a webpage (of course, without the XML and DOCTYPE tags), but not when used as a CSS background. **Why isn't CSS setting this SVG image as the repeating background of a DOM element?**

### SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg>
<SVG XMLNS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" XMLNS:XLINK="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" VIEWBOX="0 0 16 16">
  <TITLE>Translucent White Stripes</TITLE>
  <DESC>Translucent bottom-left-to-top-right diagonal white stripes</DESC>

  <POLYGON POINTS="00,16 16,00 08,00 00,08" STYLE="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.5"/>
  <POLYGON POINTS="08,16 16,08 16,16"       STYLE="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.5"/>
</SVG>
```

### CSS

```
.striped {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url("http://BHStudios.org/_images/backgrounds/translucentWhiteStripes.svg");
  background-size:16px 16px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>SVG Test</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <DIV CLASS="striped">Striped</DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here's a JSBin in case that helps: http://jsbin.com/isihuy/3/edit

### Edits to fix

---

Here are the code changes that I made to fix it:

### SVG

I re-encoded it in UTF-8 and made a not of this in the XML tag. I removed the `viewbox` attribute and replaced it with `height` and `width`. I changed all the SVG tag and attribute cases to the W3C-specified case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" width="16">
  <title>Translucent White Stripes</title>
  <desc>Translucent bottom-left-to-top-right diagonal white stripes</desc>

  <polygon points="00,16 16,00 08,00 00,08" style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.5"/>
  <polygon points="08,16 16,08 16,16"       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.5"/>
</svg>
```

### web.config

Turns out this was actually the biggest problem: The server was dishing it out as an `application/octet-stream`, despite me adding the proper `mimeMap` for SVG to the `web.config` file. To fix this, I had to precede it with a `remove` tag:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg"  mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe its a issue that you did not set the size of the SVG? (width, height) ?

Comment: What browser are you using, what version, and what OS?

Comment: I'm rather a surprised it rendered given that SVG is case sensitive and you've written all the tags in upper case.

Comment: @Nitram I was under the impression that those are deprecated...

Comment: @JulesMazur All current top 5 browsers, Windows 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is normally case sensitive. The only time it isn't is if you embed it in a case insensitive container like a HTML document. Fix the case of all your SVG tags and attributes in your standalone SVG file to be per the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) and remove the invalid `<!DOCTYPE svg>` line and you should be OK.